# jQuery File Upload Plugin with PHP/MySQL - page displaying HTML source

Tags: jquery, file, upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

This is a very odd problem. I'm attempting to get the plugin working to save images in mysql, am following the github wiki.

According to the wiki, you add an init function, so I added it at the bottom of the document head:

```
<script>
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'server/php/'
}).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    data.formData = data.context.find(':input').serializeArray();
});
</script>
```

The wiki offers some Extension php code to make it work with a mysql db. I believe you either add it within page body or as an include file. I have tried both ways and it makes no difference.

```
<?php
$options = array(
  'delete_type' => 'POST',
...
...
$upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler($options);
?>
```

I copied the php text verbatim except that I changed
    require('UploadHandler.php'); 
to 
    require('server/php/UploadHandler.php');
which is where I found the file in the distribution.

I created the database, no problem. When I visit the development/test page, it displays as HTML source code, as if you were viewing a text file. See: http://www.dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/jquery-file-upload/index-dev.php

Looking at the php code, if I comment out the next to last line ($upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler($options);), then the page displays correctly but that defeats the function/purpose. I don't see anything obvious causing the break.

Answer (score 0):

It was user-error resulting from vagueness in the documentation. The documentation mentioned using specified code to extend the index.php. Unfortunately it didn't specify which index.php and I had targeted the main one. Providing you don't modify the directory structure there is the folder, `server/php`, and in that folder an index.php file, also UploadHandler.php. The extension code referred to replaces server/php/index.php.

If you want to customize the sizes of uploaded files, you do that in UploadFile.php. If you wish to change the upload folder find that parameter in js/main.js.

To edit the valid uploadable file types, edit js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js

I also figured out how to update the main index.php and download template section so that you can re-edit title and description, doing so with some javascript and ajax.  The working page can be found at:

http://www.dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/jquery-file-upload/index.php